# Saving an array of objects to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have an array of type [User] and I want to save it in Core Data and later display it in a Table View. Here are my functions for saving and retrieving the data:

```
func saveUserData(_ users: [User]) {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)
    for user in users {
        newUser.setValue(user.id, forKey: "id")
        newUser.setValue(user.name, forKey: "name")
        newUser.setValue(user.email, forKey: "email")
        newUser.setValue(user.phone, forKey: "phone")
        newUser.setValue(user.website, forKey: "website")
        newUser.setValue(user.city, forKey: "city")
        newUser.setValue(user.lat, forKey: "lat")
        newUser.setValue(user.long, forKey: "long")
    }
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Success")
    } catch {
        print("Error saving: \(error)")
    }
}

func retrieveSavedUsers() -> [User]? {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    var retrievedUsers: [User] = []
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        if !results.isEmpty {
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                guard let id = result.value(forKey: "id") as? Int else { return nil }
                guard let name = result.value(forKey: "name") as? String else { return nil }
                guard let email = result.value(forKey: "email") as? String else { return nil }
                guard let phone = result.value(forKey: "phone") as? String else { return nil }
                guard let website = result.value(forKey: "website") as? String else { return nil }
                guard let city = result.value(forKey: "city") as? String else { return nil }
                guard let lat = result.value(forKey: "lat") as? String else { return nil }
                guard let long = result.value(forKey: "long") as? String else { return nil }
                let user = User(with: id, name: name, email: email, phone: phone, website: website, city: city, lat: lat, long: long)
                retrievedUsers.append(user)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error retrieving: \(error)")
    }
    return retrievedUsers
}
```

Retrieving works just fine, but the problem is it only saves the last object of type User in Core Data. It seems that when I am iterating trough users when I am saving them, each iteration overwrites the user object instead saving a new one. Any idea how to fix this or is there any better way of saving an array of custom objects into Core Data?

Comment: Nice answer,I wanted to ask, the type "User" is declared as a normal class or as a NSManagedObject?

Comment: @bellaGU User is defined like this `class User: Mappable`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are only creating one user entity, then just writing over it each time. The problem is that just before you loop through your users array, you create a new entity. **You should be doing this for every user in the array.** It's a very easy fix, just swap two lines. See below for the correct code:

```
func saveUserData(_ users: [User]) {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    for user in users {
        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)
        newUser.setValue(user.id, forKey: "id")
        newUser.setValue(user.name, forKey: "name")
        newUser.setValue(user.email, forKey: "email")
        newUser.setValue(user.phone, forKey: "phone")
        newUser.setValue(user.website, forKey: "website")
        newUser.setValue(user.city, forKey: "city")
        newUser.setValue(user.lat, forKey: "lat")
        newUser.setValue(user.long, forKey: "long")
    }
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Success")
    } catch {
        print("Error saving: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing a similar thing just that I also have core data constraints in place. On adding entities in a loop core data crashes with a message : "Unique constraint Violation: "