# swift core data how should I save and fetch the one to many relationship and assign value to my viewModel entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

im using UIKit delegate to manage app lifecycle but using swiftUI do the UI stuff.

lets say I have following data model entities, and i want to cached it via core data.

```swift
class ClassEntity: Codable {
    var classTitleName: String
    var classRank: Int
    var students: [StudentEntity]
    var teachers: [TeacherEntity]
    
    init (classTitleName: String,
          classRank: Int,
          students: [StudentEntity],
          teachers: [TeacherEntity]) {
        self.classTitleName = classTitleName
        self.classRank = classRank
        self.students = students
        self.teachers = teachers
    }
    
}


class StudentEntity: Codable {
    var studentName: String
    var studentGender: String
    
    init(studentName: String,
         studentGender: String){
        self.studentName = studentName
        self.studentGender = studentGender
    }
}

class TeacherEntity: Codable{
    var teacherName: String
    var teacherGender: String
    
    init(teacherName: String,
         teacherGender: String){
        self.teacherName = teacherName
        self.teacherGender = teacherGender
    }
}
```

so base on above entities, i created core data entity like following:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Then, lets say i have two viewModel called `SaveClassInfoViewModel` `FetchCachedClassInfoViewModel`, first one do save and second one do fetch

so the ViewModel will be like :

```
class SaveClassInfoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var schoolTotalClass: [ClassEntity]
    init(schoolTotalClass: [ClassEntity]) {
        self.schoolTotalClass = schoolTotalClass // data will be inject from previous VC , lets say we have data there.
    }
    
    func saveSchoolTotalClassInfo() {
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
          }
        
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        // how should i save data to cache ?
    }
}
```

```swift
class FetchCachedClassInfoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var schoolTotalClass: [ClassEntity] = []
    
    func fetchData() {
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
          }
        
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        // how should i do fetch so that im able to assign all the stored data to `schoolTotalClass` ?
        // if able to assign cached data to @Published wrapped schoolTotalClass?
        // once i got data , i can consume `@Published var schoolTotalClass` in view file directly
    }
}
```

how should i do save and fetch there, is my core data entity definition correct ? thanks very much

Comment: Why do you need two models (Custom classes **and** Core Data)? Save the data directly in Core Data. To establish the relationship set the ***one*** side of the to-many relationship. The inversion is set automatically.

Comment: because im using the custom classes in other places as well, lets say i get all the custom classes data from api call and i parse the data from api json to my custom classes data model entity , then i want to cache it as well, so i wanna pass all the data from api json to core data model

Comment: I would understand it if the custom classes conformed to `Codable`, It seems that you have a third model to parse the JSON data into. Consider that It is possible to adopt `Decodable` in Core Data entities.

Comment: yeah it conform to `Codable`

Comment: I assume the relationships are many-to-many?

Comment: yeah its one to many

Comment: So it’s _not_ many-to-may? Your use of the word “yeah” is confusing. So are you saying a student can take only one class and a teacher teaches only one class?

Comment: sorry , not many to many , is one to many, student and teacher can only in one class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather creating relation like this you can do it saving the class id in teacher and student and get them on the basis of id like as:

```
class ClassEntity {
    let id:String
    var classTitleName: String
    var classRank: Int

    
    init (id:String,
          classTitleName: String,
          classRank: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.classTitleName = classTitleName
        self.classRank = classRank
    }
    
}
```

then your teacher and student

```
class StudentEntity {
    var classId:String
    var studentName: String
    var studentGender: String
    
    init(classId:String,studentName: String,
         studentGender: String){
        self.classId = classId
        self.studentName = studentName
        self.studentGender = studentGender
    }
}

class TeacherEntity {
    var classId:String
    var teacherName: String
    var teacherGender: String
    
    init(classId:String,teacherName: String,
         teacherGender: String){
        self.classId = classId
        self.teacherName = teacherName
        self.teacherGender = teacherGender
    }
}
```

then create coredatastack

import Foundation
import CoreData

```
class CoreDataStack: NSObject {
   
    private let modelName: String
    lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        return self.storeContainer.viewContext
    }()
    
    init(modelName: String) {
        self.modelName = modelName
    }
    
    private lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
       
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.modelName)
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
        return container
    }()
    
    
    func saveContext () {
        guard managedContext.hasChanges else { return }
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    func updateContext() {
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    func clearChanges() {
        managedContext.rollback()
    }
    
    func deleteReminder(reminder:Reminder) {
        managedContext.delete(reminder)
        updateContext()
    }
    
    func deleteNote(note:Note) {
        managedContext.delete(note)
        updateContext()
    }
    
    func deleteFromIds(selectedId:SubCategoryIds) {
        managedContext.delete(selectedId)
        updateContext()
    }
    
}
```

then create a manager

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {
    
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    private init(){}
    lazy var coreDataStack = CoreDataStack(modelName: "YourModelName")
    
    func allClasses() -> [ClassEntity] {
        let fetechRequest: NSFetchRequest<ClassEntity> = ClassEntity.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let results = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetechRequest)
            return results
        } catch {
            
        }
        return [ClassEntity]()
    }
    
    func allStudentOfClass(classId:String) -> [StudentEntity] {
        let fetechRequest: NSFetchRequest< StudentEntity > = StudentEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetechRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "classId == %@",
                                              argumentArray: [classId])
        do {
            let results = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetechRequest)
            return results
        } catch {
            
        }
        return [StudentEntity]()
    }
    
      func allTeacherOfClass(classId:String) -> [TeacherEntity] {
         let fetechRequest: NSFetchRequest<TeacherEntity> = TeacherEntity.fetchRequest()
       fetechRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "classId == %@",
                                          argumentArray: [classId])
        do {
          let results = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetechRequest)
          return results
       } catch {

    }
    return [TeacherEntity]()
  }
  
    
}
```

how you can create a class

```
 func createClass() {
    let id = "Class 1" //or whatever you want to say here
    let _class = Class(context: CoreDataManger.shared.coreDataStack.managedContext)
    _class.id = id
    _class.classTitleName = "Title"
    _class.classRank = 12
    CoreDataManger.shared.coreDataStack.saveContext()
}
```

same as how create teacher with this class

```
 func addTeacher(classId:String) {
        let _class = TeacherEntity(context: CoreDataManger.shared.coreDataStack.managedContext)
        _class.classId = classId
        _class.teacherGender = "Male"
        _class.teacherName = "Alex"
        CoreDataManger.shared.coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }
```

Comment: sorry whats the `Reminder`and some other arguments here

Comment: edited: reminder replace with your entity name 
first you have to create your NSManagedobjectSubClass Manually of your entity by selecting entity in your model

Comment: argumentArray: [c] here meaning ?

Comment: c was a typo you can replace c with [classId] as I edited the answer

Comment: the `ClassEntity ` or `StudentEntity` or `TeacherEntity` over here is my custom data model or the coredata entity ? if it is my custom entity , `let fetechRequest: NSFetchRequest<ClassEntity> = ClassEntity.fetchRequest()` , it will popup `Type 'ClassEntity' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'` , so i assume entities here should be the entities of core data. and the `classId` is the relationship name with `Class` entity , correct ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72458122/14699332 here you can see how create NSManagedObjectSubclasses after creating that add above

Comment: the classId is foreign key here in teacher and student table you can save teacher with a class Id and student with a classId or maybe you should have to create a an array for one teacher to many classes or else

Comment: okay , thanks very much , i will have a try

Comment: but i have one question left though. when i try to delete the whole Class entity and i set student and teacher relationship as cascade already , i wrote like this : ```func deleteCachedClass(classId: Int) {
        let request: NSFetchRequest< Class > = Class.fetchRequest()
        do { let classes = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(request)
            for _ in classes {
              coreDataStack.managedContext.delete(classes[index])}
        } catch  {} }``` but class will be deleted but teachers and students still in cache. any set i missed?

Comment: you should have to delete student and teacher first by getting them class id and delete them then delete the class

Comment: okay i get it , thanks